# python classes and values

Tags: python, list, class, types

I need to send data from a file to a class in another file, and copy that data into another file that contains a class.

In other words, I ask for the following data:

```
name = input("Name")
number = input("Number")
years = input("Years Worked")
salary = input("salary")
new = Staff.addEmployee(name,number,years,salary)
```

Basically, I want to send that data into a function that is in a class in another file called staff.py. Then, the data that is sent to the staff.py, it needs to be appended to a list that is created when the class is initialized. For that, I created the code:

```
class Staff:

    def __init__(self):
        self.EmployeeList = []

    def addEmployee(self, name, number, YearsWorked, Salary):
        addemployee = employee.Employee(name, number,YearsWorked, Salary)
        addemployee.setYearsWorked(YearsWorked)
        addemployee.setSalary(Salary)
        addemployee.setHolidayEntitlement()
        self.employeeList.append(addemployee)
```

To conclude, I need to copy that data to another file, called employee.py (as you may see on the code, I am calling the class Employee that is in another file. In the employee.py, I only wrote the following code:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name , number , YearsWorked, Salary):
        self._Name = Name
        self._StaffNr = StaffNr
        self._YearsWorked = 0
        self._Salary = 0
        self._HolidayEntitlement = 0
```

In general, I'm trying to pass data from a file, to another, and another .. but I can't. I'm struggling! Can I have some help please?

Comment: I think inheritance should help or you can make employee list being an array of objects of the class Employee

Comment: File and module are different things. I think you want to send the data from staff.py module to Employee.py module? Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, But im confused because on the employee.py I can't create a list to pass the values .. on the staff.py I have a list to append the values.. oh god :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your staff.py

```
from employee import Employee

class Staff:

    def __init__(self):
        self.EmployeeList = []

    def addEmployee(self, name, number, YearsWorked, Salary):
        employee_obj = Employee(name, number, YearsWorked, Salary)
        employee_obj.print_employee_details()
        self.EmployeeList.append(employee_obj)

name = input("Name")
number = input("Number")
years = input("Years Worked")
salary = input("salary")
staff_obj = Staff()
new = staff_obj.addEmployee(name,number,years,salary)
```

Your employee.py looks somthing like this.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name , number , YearsWorked, Salary):
        self._Name = name
        self._StaffNr = number
        self._YearsWorked = YearsWorked
        self._Salary = Salary
        self._HolidayEntitlement = 0

    def print_employee_details(self):
        print ("Employee Name is {} working since past {} having salary {}").format(self._Name, self._YearsWorked, self._Salary)
```

Run staff.py

```
Name: Ana
Number: 001
Years Worked: 3
salary:30000
Employee Name is  Ana working since past 3 years having salary 30000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like in staff.py you have `employee.Employee(...`, you need to initialize you `Staff` object. in tour main file. In addition, if you want to have a list populated, you need a loop of some kind. So it should appear like:

```
from staff import Staff
mystaff = Staff()
for _ in range(100): #for 100 employees, can replace with while with a stop condition
    name = input("Name")
    number = input("Number")
    years = input("Years Worked")
    salary = input("salary")
    mystaff.addEmployee(name,number,years,salary)
```

Also note that you misspelled your variable at the last line of `addEmployee`, should be:

```
self.EmployeeList.append(addemployee)
```

And, that your Employee constructor recieves YearsWorked, Salary but doesn't use them, and that variable names are usually lower cased in python.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of `sending data to another file` is one I would avoid. Instead, think of your program structure like this:

- Define your classes in separate files (or if they're related and short, you can put them in the same file)
- Write a separate file that interacts with your user with the classes that you defined. This will be your main program, i.e. takes input, prints stuff, *saves data*

  - *saves data*: you can save the user input in a file, and load it every time your program is started. Maybe that is what you meant by "sending data..."? This is probably best achieved with a database, you can look into sqlite, which is a database that comes with python and its very simple and powerful. You can also save data in text files (which might be easier if you're not familiar with sql)
- Write additional modules to extend your program, (e.g. maybe email someone a list of staff members every second Tuesday of months that don't end "ry")

Currently, you have two files (that you've shared with us), staff.py & employee.py that store information regarding the two classes Staff & Employee. That's great so far.

Next steps:

- your Staff class' addEmployee method calls the employee object's setYearsWorked & setSalary methods when they're defined in the constructor. These don't seem to be needed. The method to set holiday also seems redundant here.
- you staff.py file should import the employee module (make sure you have the following lines at the beginning of staff.py

  import employee

example staff.py:

```
# staff.py
import employee


class Staff(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.employee_list = []

    def add_employee(self,
                     name,
                     number,
                     years_worked,
                     salary):

        new_emp = employee.Employee(name,
                                    number,
                                    years_worked,
                                    salary)
        self.employee_list.append(new_emp)
```

example employee.py:

```
#employee.py
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, name, number, years_worked, salary):
        self._name = name
        self._number = number
        self._years_worked = years_worked
        self._salary = salary
        self._holiday_entitlement = 0
```

- Then you need to create the "main.py" file, which could do some / all of the following (technically, you could do this inside of staff.py or employee.py as well, but separating this logic in a new file is cleaner):

  - ask the user for input to create the new employee
  - maybe: print all employees
  - maybe: print a particular employee's details
  - maybe: allow the user to update an employee's details
  - maybe: store the staff information in a file or database (advanced usage)
  - maybe: load staff information from a file or database (advanced usage)

I created a [github repository](https://github.com/haleemur/anagrou) for this project, so you can check out how my simple example would work. To test it out, you can clone it, cd into the directory, and run the following (note, the example won't work on python2.x):

```
python3 main.py
```

Finally, a note about code style. The python community has very strict guidelines about code quality & formatting. This is because code readability is a very important aspect of the python language. The community standard is codified in [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Please have a look :). This is why in my example code I've switched some of the variable names from camelCase to under_scored.

Comment: Will you marry me? You just made my day. You don't have idea how much you safe and helped me, this is a coursework for the university. I am so grateful! Thanks!

Comment: haha! Thanks but I'm already married :). My wife got a kick out of this! We can't even have an affair because we're on different continents :P... As, this is your homework assignment, please don't copy my code over directly, although I encourage you to fork/clone and run it. Think of alternate ways to implement user interaction, maybe look into argparse and sqlite modules.

Comment: ahahah I was kidding :) Yes, I just will your code as base, so I can have an idea how it works, and how do you call methods, functions, etc. Many thanks! :)